# Time Capsule external hard drive (usb)

Tags: time-capsule, external-disk

I've added an external (Freecom XS 1TB) hard disk to my Time Capsule. However, this one's Mac Journaled (HFS+) formatted and does not display in Finder until I add a hub between the TC and external HDD.

The Freecom XS is powered, and when I add a Western Digital HDD without powering it displays in Finder.

What am I missing? Both are formatted Mac Journaled HFS+.

Comment: what kinda hub are you talking about?

Comment: usb, as stated in the title.

Comment: so you add a USB (powered?) hub and then it works?

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't get it. The usb-hub both works, with or without power.

Comment: what do you mean the usb-hub both works? with or without power? is your hub powered or not?

Comment: Whether I power my USB hub or not, my Freecom XS is available. If I don't use a hub, it displays no disk at all. 
If I plug in my WD it displays without hub.

Comment: that is totally messed up, im sorry then i don't have a straight to solution for that!